# Having a problem loading in data to child component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-props

I am building a gallery where you click on the image and it will load in a separate component using props, this image is a URL, taken from a hard-coded array, where the src is loaded as a background image via CSS. My challenge is connecting the data to that component. I have tried connecting the data from parent to child with callbacks, but no luck. I think what I am trying to do is connect components sideways, and I don't want to use redux, as I am not familiar.

Note: I am aware you can just load the image in GalleryContainer.js using `window.location.href = "props.src/"`, however, I want the image to load in the Image component that will act as a container to hold the image giving the user other options such as downloading the image, etc...

Note: I have tried importing the Image component in Gallery.js and rendering it like so:  `<Image src={props.src} id={props.id}/>`, and I find the data connects just fine, but this does not help keep the component separate.

What I have already :
I have a route in app.js that allows me to go to the image route path just fine it’s loading in the url from props.src in the image component that is my challenge

**UPDATE: SOLVED [Click here to see the solution!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847263/how-do-i-redirect-to-an-external-link-in-react)**

Here is the code:

GalleryList.js

```
import Gallery from "./Gallery";
import Header from "./UI/Header";
import Footer from "./UI/Footer";

import styles from "./Gallery.module.css";

const DUMMY_IMAGES = [
  {
    id: "img1",
    src: "https://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-vbN8fNz/1/X3/i-vbN8fNz-X3.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "img2",
    src: "https://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-fSkvQJS/1/X3/i-fSkvQJS-X3.jpg",
  },
  {
    id: "img3",
    src: "https://photos.smugmug.com/photos/i-pS99jb4/0/X3/i-pS99jb4-X3.jpg",
  },
];

const GalleryList = () => {
  const imagesList = DUMMY_IMAGES.map((image) => (
    <Gallery id={image.id} key={image.id} src={image.src} />
  ));

  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <ul className={styles.wrapper}>
        <li className={styles.list}>{imagesList}</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="/">Home</a>
      <Footer />
    </>
  );
};

export default GalleryList;
```

Gallery.js

```
import GalleryConatiner from "./UI/GalleryContainer";

import styles from "./Gallery.module.css";

const Gallery = (props) => {
  return (
    <>
      <div className={styles["gal-warp"]}>
        <GalleryConatiner id={props.id} key={props.id} src={props.src} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Gallery;
```

GalleryContainer.js

```
import styles from "../Gallery.module.css";

const GalleryConatiner = (props) => {
  const selectedImg = () => {
    if (props.id) {
      // window.location.href = `image/${props.src}`;
      window.location.href = "image/"
    }
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      <li className={styles["gallery-list"]}>
        <div
          onClick={selectedImg}
          className={styles["div-gallery"]}
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${props.src}`,
            height: 250,
            backgroundSize: "cover",
          }}
        ></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
};
export default GalleryConatiner;
```

Image.js

```
import styles from "./Image.module.css";

const Image = (props) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <h1 className={styles["h1-wrapper"]}>Image:{props.id}</h1>
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <div
          className={styles["image-container"]}
          style={{
            backgroundImage: `url(${props.src}`,
          }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

Comment: You can use a modal view to show the current image and download but there.

Comment: @AmilaSenadheera, thank you I am aware I can use modal but I want the component to load in another page

Comment: Okay, then You should be using react router for that. Setup Swith and Routes in root file

Comment: I have a route in app.js that is not my problem, I can go to the image route just fine it’s loading in the url from props.src in the image component that is the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use the router `Link` to pass data via "state" on the `to` property.

From React Router's [documentation](https://reactrouter.com/native/api/Link/to-object):

```
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: "/images",
    state: { imgUrl: props.src }
  }}
/>
```

Comment: Thank you, @Taylor Newton. This worked partially:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67847263/how-do-i-redirect-to-an-external-link-in-react